Where is the flaw in this argument for faster than light communication?
Why is the following argument incorrect?
Following the well known quantum teleportation algorithm (described here), it is established that the speed of teleportation can be no faster than the speed of light.
But suppose, the sender, wants to teleport the state of a single qubit:
$$ |\Phi\rangle = a|0\rangle + b |1\rangle $$
for some  amplitudes $a$, $b$,
where $a$ is a complex number, and $b$ is of the form of a complex number
multiplied by $e^{i\theta}$ where $i$ is the square root of $-1$. The value of $\theta$ can be found
correctly e.g. by using some phase recovery algorithm . The sender teleports the above state T times (e.g. we may take T to be more than 1022 to be concrete).
Then, according to the known basic teleportation protocol above, the receiver gets the teleported get Phi  correct 25% of the time, the other 75% of the time the receiver need to apply an $X$ or $Z$ gate ,depending on 2 bits of classical information sent by the teleportation protocol, to recover $|\Phi\rangle$ correctly.
Now consider a variation of the teleportation protocol where the  receiver does NOT apply the $X$ or $Z$ gate and the sender does not send any bit of classical information thus there is a 25% chance $|\Phi\rangle$ is in the correct state.
Now suppose the sender encodes a message into the binary expansion of theta e.g. using the binary expansions of the ASCII codes of the letters. Something like "The message I sent is as follows. You decoded it correctly"
The message always starts with "The message I sent is as follows", so the receiver knows the message is correctly decoded as it starts with the words above, or some other sufficiently long phrase that is unlikely to occur randomly.
Then 25% (of the T times) of the time the receiver will decode the message correctly by using the variant teleportation algorithm, which does not use the $X$ and $Z$ gates, and so recover theta and hence the message correctly.
The other 75% (of the T times) of the time the message will not be decoded correctly so is ignored.
But no classical information was sent by the sender.
To summarize the above, use the known teleportation protocol, without the $X$ or $Z$ gates, and encode a message into the value of $\theta$. The value of $\theta$ is recovered using some phase estimation algorithm 25% of T times. Thus the message is recovered at least 20% of the time correctly.
Therefore faster than light communication has occurred. But as we know it is not possible to send information faster than light so where is the error in my argument above?

Was this copied from somewhere else? The first paragraph says: "the well known quantum teleportation algorithm as described here under the ¨Formal presentation¨ section..." What/Where is the "Formal Presentation Section"?

fixed it-I put in the wikipedia link to the well known teleportation protocol. yes the title  ¨Formal presentation¨ was copied or quoted from the above wikipedia link in my question.

You can only retrieve one bit of information from a single qubit. So you cannot estimate the phase $\theta$ with higher precision from one copy of your qubit. You won't get $T$ copies of the phase (where $1/4$th is correct), from which you would easily deduce the proper $\theta$. Indeed, you need multiple copies of the state to properly estimate $\theta$. But you don't know what $25%$ of the T states in total have the correct phase. So you cannot estimate $\theta$.

The problem is that your statement: "Theta can be found correctly e.g. by using some phase recovery algorithm", is incorrect.
My guess is that you are probably referring to an algorithm like quantum phase estimation (QPE), but that does not work in this case. The way QPE works is:
Given a unitary $U$ and an eigenvector $|\psi\rangle$, such that:
$$ U|\psi\rangle = e^{2\pi i\theta}|\psi\rangle,$$
QPE estimates the value of $\theta$ in the form of a statevector $|\tilde{\theta}\rangle$, where $\tilde{\theta}$ is the binary approximation of $\theta$.
The issue in your case is that, you're not trying to find an eigenvalue of a unitary $U$, but rather find the value of $\theta$ for a state already given to Bob in the form:
$$|\Phi\rangle = a|0\rangle + b e^{i\theta}|1\rangle \; | \;a, b \in \mathbb{R}$$
Since Bob does not have $U$ but rather $|\Phi\rangle$, the only way he could recover $b e^{i\theta}$ is by performing state tomography. Assuming Bob can indeed repeat the teleportation experiment many times to perform tomography, Bob will not just receive $|\Phi\rangle$ from Alice; instead he will get all of the four possible states below with equal probability:
$$
\begin{aligned}
|\Phi_1\rangle &= a|0\rangle + b e^{i\theta}|1\rangle
\\
|\Phi_2\rangle &= a|0\rangle - b e^{i\theta}|1\rangle
\\
|\Phi_3\rangle &= a|1\rangle + b e^{i\theta}|0\rangle
\\
|\Phi_4\rangle &= a|1\rangle - b e^{i\theta}|0\rangle .
\end{aligned}
$$
So performing tomography will result in a mixture of these four states, which means you cannot recover the correct probability amplitudes of just one of these.

So what is the flaw in the following comment then,  Alice can influence the state 0> or 1>  that she measures by removing energy or inserting energy into her measured quibit-e.g. by shining light onto the qubit she measures for example -thus she can influence what Bob measures to be a 0> or 1>. So hence transmit information faster than light. This comment must be course must be incorrect somewhere-but where?

Any local change Alice performs to her qubit leaves Bob's qubit's unchanged. For example, say Alice and Bob share the state $\sqrt{1/2}(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)$ and that "shinning light" corresponds to a unitary $U$ Alice applies to her qubit. The final state will then be $(I \otimes U)\sqrt{1/2}(|00\rangle + |11\rangle) = \sqrt{1/2}(|0\rangle \otimes U|0\rangle + |1\rangle \otimes U|1\rangle)$. Notice that U only affects the state Alice's qubit, and not Bob's.
